# Deploying SQL Server Project Items to a SQL Server does not affect Table Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am fairly new at this, but I am deploying a DB project to the SQL server. I modified a table in the project, but when I successfully deploy to the server the table did not change, The changes to the table was not there. Am I missing something, or is it that for tables I have to manually change it?

**Update**

So I was experimenting with things and it seems that I needed to do a schema compare, then manually update the schema. This though resulted in some data lost. Deploy is suppose to do the same thing with out the data lost? Or is my definition of deploy completely off.

Comment: What is the table structure what changes you made ? A little bit more information please

Comment: I thought I was having this problem once. Fought it for about 3 hours. Finally I realized that I had 2 copies of the database on my server and I was pushing the changes to copy A, and looking for the changes in copy B. Lesson: Make sure you're looking in the right database.

Comment: @MuhammedAli I basically dropped 2 column, and added one column to the table schema

Comment: @alroc It's the right DB I only have one.

Comment: @MuhammedAli to be more specific what I did was modify the .sql file so that when the table is created it is created without the 2 columns and has the new column instead.

Comment: Make sure that your Display of the DB and structures is not stale.  I'm not sure about VS Data Tools, but SSMS (Management Studio) has an incredibly "sticky" cache.  You have to force-refresh it all the time when you're changing definitions with scripts or procedures.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I tried that no luck.